# Angularjs - Http get está retornando o html da página principal ao inves do json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http, get

Amigos,
Tenho uma web app que funciona normalmente quando instalada em localhost. Mas quando faço o deploy em um server diferente o http get retorna o html da página principal ao inves de retornar o json. Detalhe isso ocorre no chrome e firefox. No IE funciona normalmente.
Alguem pode me ajudar

Comment: Poste o resultado HTML que está retornando, isso pode ser um erro de requisição e estar retornando a página de erro.

Answer (score 1):

Você está usando $http?

É possível que seja um problema de cross domain

Sugiro dar uma lida na resolução de um problema similar aqui mesmo no SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905912/how-to-load-a-cross-domain-json-with-http-in-angularjs-1-0-8-as-it-does-with-1